# How can I delete specific words or string from a python string without trimming it from other words in Python?

Tags: python, string, replace

I would like to know how to remove specific words from a string in python without deleting them from other words they composed.

For example if I want to remove 'is' from the following sentence:

```
s = 'isabelle is in Paris'
```

The .replace() function delete 'is' in 'isabelle' and in 'Paris':

```
s = 'isabelle is in Paris'
s.replace('is', '')
```

It gives me `abelle in Par` But I want `isabelle in Paris`. Is there a way to delete only 'is'?

I tried: `s.replace(' is ', '')` with a space each side of 'is' but in this case 'is' is not removed in the string `s = 'Isabelle is, as you know, in Paris'`

Thank you

Comment: I would suggest learning about Regular Expressions [link](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html). For example, you could possibly write a RegEx using `re.sub` or `re.replace`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a regular expression instead of replacing an ordinary string. You can then use `\b` in the regexp to match word boundaries.

```
import re
s = re.sub(r'\bis\b', '', s)
```